# Moving an element in XML file with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a a XML file that looks like this,

```
 <XML>
   <article article-type="research">
   <article-meta>
   <abstract>
      <p> lorisum......</p>
   </abstract>
   <abstract abstract-type="summary">
      <p>lorisum summary</p>
   </abstract>
   </article-meta>

   <body>
    <sec>
     <p>
      ......
     </p>
    </sec>
    <sec sec-type="clinical">
     <p> clinical test</p>
    </sec>
    </body>
    </article>
    <XML>
```

The question is how do I move the clinical sec into the untyped abstract with xslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the clinical sec like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="abstract[not(@abstract-type)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//sec[@sec-type='clinical']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="sec[@sec-type='clinical']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<XML>
  <article article-type="research">
    <article-meta>
        <abstract>
            <p> lorisum......</p>
            <sec sec-type="clinical">
                <p> clinical test</p>
            </sec>
        </abstract>
        <abstract abstract-type="summary">
            <p>lorisum summary</p>
        </abstract>
    </article-meta>
    <body>
        <sec>
            <p>
                ......
            </p>
        </sec>
    </body>
  </article>
</XML>
```

The template just copies everything from the original input XML. The template matching `sec[@sec-type='clinical']` is empty, so this section will be removed from this copy. The template matching the abstract without the abstract-type attribute -  `abstract[not(@abstract-type)]` - copies the abstract and adds a copy of `sec[@sec-type='clinical']`.